# Programatically adding rows in table using loop but just last record gets display

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This code add last row in the Table . I mean just last record get displayed
I thought its a problem of viewstate so tried to EnableViewState but it says that its not like that

```
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Table tb = new Table();
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();


  for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    emp = con.GetNextEmployee();
      if (emp != null)
      {
       tc1.Text = emp.name;
       tc2.Text = emp.position;
       tc3.Text = emp.ext;
       tr1.Cells.Add(tc1);
       tr1.Cells.Add(tc2);
       tr1.Cells.Add(tc3);
       tb.Rows.Add(tr1);
      }
   }
 Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
```

Kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move these lines into the loop:

```
    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
```

why part:
actually you don't need to re-define them.

but the objects must be RE-created after you add them to your table.

because:
when you add a row/cell to the table. row/cells' "reference" is being added to table.

so, second time you change the row or cell, actually, you are changing the row/cell "that is already in your table"

Comment: answer is right but why is there a need to define the references every time

Comment: actually you don't need to re-define them. but the objects must be RE-created after you add them to your table. because: when you add a row/cell to the table. row/cells' "reference" is being added to table. so, second time you change the row or cell, actually, you are changing the row/cell "that is already in your table"

Comment: so the total count of 'table' object made will always remain one all the time because its not a new reference  ,it is just re created 
Thanks

Comment: yes. when you re create the row/cell object there will be completely new row in the stack memory. otherwise you will always work on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Table tbl = new Table();

TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
tr = new TableRow();
tc = new TableCell();

tc.Text = "Your Cell Text";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);

tc = new TableCell();
//Add new cell and add code to your cell
}
```